# error is Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I got an error

> Column 'Employee.EmpID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

SQL code:

```
with cte(stu_id,term_cd, spcl_cd  ) as 
(
    Select 
        zt.[STU_ID], zt.TERM_CD, zt.SPCL_CD 
    From 
        SR0TZT(nolock) zt 
    Inner Join 
       (Select 
            STU_ID, MIN(TERM_SEQ_NUM) MinPoint, SPCL_CD 
        From SR0TZT 
        Group By STU_ID) tbl1 On zt.STU_ID = tbl1.STU_ID
    Where 
        tbl1.MinPoint = zt.TERM_SEQ_NUM
        and zt.STU_ID = '202716354'
        and tbl1.SPCL_CD = zt.SPCL_CD
)
SELECT 
    zt.[STU_ID], zt.[TERM_CD], zt.[SPCL_CD], 
    zt.[SPCL_STRT_TERM], zt.TERM_SEQ_NUM, t.term_id 
FROM
    SR0TZT zt 
JOIN
    cte ON zt.STU_ID = cte.stu_id
WHERE
    zt.STU_ID = '202716354'
```

Condition is:

- For each unique combination of `TZT.STU_ID` and `TZT.SPCL_CD` where `TZT.COLL_CD = ''`, display the `TZT.TERM_CD` with the minimum `TZT.TERM_SEQ_NUM`.

For UID 202716354, based on the above rule, the value of this column is incorrect for both specialization codes.

Comment: I think column SPCL_CD is invalid, I see no EmpId?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand why you are getting an error for 'Employee.EmpID' as it doesn't appear in your query.

At first look I can see that the following part of your SQL code (the derived table 'tbl1')...

```
Select STU_ID,MIN(TERM_SEQ_NUM) MinPoint,SPCL_CD From SR0TZT Group By STU_ID
```

..is incorrect and would cause a similar error because SPCL_CD isn't used in an aggregate function (such as MIN) or in the GROUP BY.  You should change it to:-

```
Select STU_ID,MIN(TERM_SEQ_NUM) MinPoint,SPCL_CD From SR0TZT Group By STU_ID, SPCL_CD
```

And that should solve your problem.

Comment: when i used this below query

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this below script:

```
Select STU_ID,MIN(TERM_SEQ_NUM) MinPoint,SPCL_CD From SR0TZT Group By STU_ID
```

It should be:

```
Select STU_ID,MIN(TERM_SEQ_NUM) MinPoint,SPCL_CD From SR0TZT Group By STU_ID, SPCL_CD
```

Every column that you put in `select`, you should put them too in `group by`.